# Sorting arrays with quickSort (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, quicksort

Okay, so I need to sort an array in both ascending and descending order using quick sort. I have code that works properly for the ascending, and properly *most* of the time for descending, but it will randomly not work well for descending... most often when the smallest number is in the original first position. So I might have an array of (261, 940, 604, 655) which means it should output as (940, 655, 604, 261) but what I get is (655,940, 604, 261). However, I cannot figure out *why* the array does not always sort properly. Any hints?

```
private void sortButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
            // just how the array is filled
        for (int i =0; i<numNum; i++)
        {
             numList [4] = generator.nextInt(1000);
        }
            // call on quickSort "decending" method
        QuickSort_HighLow(numList, 0, numList.length - 1);
        for( int x=0; x <= numList.length-1; x++)
        {
            sortedOutput.setText((sortedOutput.getText())+ "\n" + numList[x] );
        }
}
public static int PartitionHighLow(int[] numbers, int left, int right)
{
    int pivot = numbers[left];
    while (true)
    {
        while (numbers[left] > pivot)
            left ++ ;

        while (numbers[right] < pivot)
            right --;

            if (left < right)
            {
                int temp = numbers[left];
                numbers[left] = numbers[right];
                numbers[right] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                return right;
            }
    }
}

   public static void QuickSort_HighLow(int[] arr, int left, int right)
{
    // For Recusrion
    if(left < right)
    {
        int pivot = PartitionHighLow(arr, left, right);

        if(pivot < 1)
            QuickSort_HighLow(arr, left, pivot );

        if(pivot + 1 < right)
            QuickSort_HighLow(arr, pivot + 1, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. What happens in `PartitionHighLow` if you accidentally input an array with `numbers[left]==numbers[right]`...?

Comment: 2. Are you sure the condition `if(pivot < 1)` in `QuickSort_HighLow` is correct?

Comment: 1. Haven't dealt with that... Numbers are randomly generated and I don't use that many, so it's never turned up.

Comment: 2. Actually, switching the < to > seems to work! Don't know how I didn't catch that! Thank you! @CiaPan

Comment: 1. Even random numbers may get equal some day. Anyway I don't require all numbers being equal, just the two: first and last of *some* array part at *some* step of sorting. What will happen then?

Comment: 2. Actually, switching the < to > in `if(pivot < 1)` seems causing you to make unnecessary recursive calls, because `pivot` is **always** greater than one (except possibly the first call and only if the biggest number happens to be at the first position of the array) so the condition is always met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem the implementation has is that it won't work if you have equal numbers (you will keep switching them with each other if it will be chosen as pivot).

The other is in the recursion:

```
if(pivot > left + 1)
    QuickSort_HighLow(arr, left, pivot - 1);

if(pivot < right - 1)
    QuickSort_HighLow(arr, pivot + 1, right);
```

Comment: Seems to help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your partition function will do only one pass and it will stop for desc if the smallest is first. You assign it as pivot, mover it to last, calculate left==right, return length-1 and terminate. This looks like wrong implementation of quicksort